# android: how to retrieve dynamic edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to get the id of the dynamically created edit text in android for example i have created 3 editext dynamically with same name edtex and different id. how can i retrieve particular edittext from that.. thanks in advance

```
for(int i=0;i<toke.length;i++)
          {
              Log.d("","toke="+" "+toke[i]);
              if(toke[i].contains("AnswerBox"))
              {
                Log.d("","####### answerbox present ########");  
                multied=new EditText(addition.this);

                multied.setId(did);
                multied.setWidth(80);
                multied.setHeight(40);
                // tl.addView(multied);
                relay.addView(multied);
                did++;

              }
}
```

from the above code how can i retrive the edittext created at second iteration..

Comment: you can't get like that, make three different names and keep them as global and use where ever you want.

Comment: is there any option to set name for edittext dynamatically..? i had a  collection of strings and i need to set that string as edittext name..?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code to retrieve `edittext`

```
EditText edtTxt=(EditText ) findViewById(did);
```

Comment: Ohk great Pls accept my answer then :) also you can select and rate the answer by increasing upper arrow

Answer (score 0):

In android you can't get (or set) a Resource ID for a dynamically created View. But for what you are trying to do, you could extend a TextView and add the id property.

Comment: will u please explain more..?